# Get parameter passed from javascript url

Tags: javascript, url, param

i just want to know if its possible to retrrive param from js calling with passed values like this

```
myfile.js?my_parm=brol
```

My goal is to retrieve the `my_param` value from within my "myfile.js"

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

See [Calling URL parameters within a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328864/calling-url-parameters-within-a-js-file)

Answer (score 0):

No, not from within the JavaScript, the only way to access query string parameters in JavaScript is through the document or location objects. Those are only available when the script is executed within the browser.

If you are trying to access it using a templating language (like php or python) you could of course capture the querystring argument and inject information into the JavaScript code with that.